# Object variable not set (Error 91)

Tags: vb6, adodb, msflexgrid

I have a problem ADODB.RECORDSET, i have MSFlexGrid called flgFact what is filled with data and i want to add that data related on a recordset called rsDetal but when i compile the code it drop me (error 91 : Object variable or With block variable rate is not) in the if

```
Private Sub cmdeport_Click()
    Dim rsDetal As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rsDetal = flgFact.DataSource
    If Not (rsDetal.EOF And rsDetal.BOF) Then
           rsDetal.MoveFirst
           Do While Not rsDetal.EOF
           Numdocu = rsDetal(4)
           Fec_Emision = rsDetal(5)
           Totl = rsDetal(16)
           Igve = rsDetal(17)
           Totv = rsDetal(18)
           Mont_Pade = rsDetal(14)
           Mont_Paco = rsDetal(15)
           Call TEMPTRAMA(Numdocu, Fec_Em, Totl, Igve, Totv, Mont_Pade, Mont_Paco)
           rsDetal.MoveNext
           Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

i  checked my value rsDetal and the value taken from the MSFlexGrid is Nothing

Comment: You answered your own question in the last sentence of your question:  "i checked my value rsDetal and the value taken from the MSFlexGrid is Nothing":

Answer (score 0):

If your MSFlexGrid isn't bound to a DataSource then .DataSource will be Nothing.

You need to iterate through the rows of the grid and access the text in each column. Just a change to the way you are looping, and you may need to cast the string values from the grid to the correct types.

```
Dim lngRowCount As Long, lngFixedRowCount As Long, lngRowIndex As Long

lngRowCount = MSFlexGrid1.Rows
lngFixedRowCount = MSFlexGrid1.FixedRows

For lngRowIndex = lngFixedRowCount To lngRowCount - 1
    'Access values using MSFlexGrid1.TextMatrix(lngRowIndex, 0), where 0 is the column
Next lngRowIndex
```